# Bypass an escape function - SQL injection (Educational Purpose)

Tags: php, javascript, sql-injection

I am trying to simulate an SQL injection on a VM Apache server. The query I send is being converted into the part of a parameter's value i.e an escape function is restricting me.
For example if I enter `' Or 1=1;--` it will include the single quote along with the rest and consider it a singular value, thus restricting me from implementing a successful injection. 
The PHP version is Zend 2.3. SQLite DB.

**Again this is an educational exercise. Only need a hint. Not the entire answer. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: might be helpful to show your http request and the server's response

Comment: That's because a server firewall is being used block the sql injection. That's the point.

Comment: @Mogoroth Basically its a simple post request. The server checks the login twofold. Once the Username, then the hashed password. The username check uses an escape function. I wanted to know if there was another way to bypass the initial escape function.

Comment: try counteracting the ' ... and escapes or more ' ;) you have to think about it, there is nothing wrong with adding more parameters, though zend could be working differently and escaping them on the back end? share the code T__T

Comment: How can you be certain of that @desbest? There are many other possibilities for a SQLi failing.